# Criar área hachurada abaixo de curva de distribuição normal no R

Tags: r, gráfico, plot

Gostaria de criar uma área hachurada, em cinza, tal como a  da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Plotei a curva, com os dados como segue:

`dados <- c(149.3355, 140.3779, 145.7254, 149.8931, 139.6168, 149.1934, 129.6147, 134.7523, 167.8030, 171.7407, 157.5422, 160.2664, 155.4553, 142.5989, 134.9844, 148.5172, 163.1447, 131.0138, 130.2423, 167.2239, 149.4015, 145.6802, 160.3472, 121.1775, 136.7295, 162.2381, 150.7192, 117.8144, 137.3630, 158.6373, 168.0833, 133.9263, 150.9102, 149.4811, 167.4367, 178.0970, 138.4903, 148.6764, 181.0990, 167.3345, 147.0679, 156.1410, 148.8734, 140.9484, 147.6408, 134.5726, 184.6812, 134.6648, 146.8130, 167.4161)`

`x <- seq(min(dados), max(dados), length=1000)`

`curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(dados), sd=sd(dados)), col="red", lwd=2, yaxt="n", xlim=c(100,200), main = "Tempo de Transmissão via Satélite", xlab="Tempo", ylab = "Freq")`

O gráfico acima, que eu criei, é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O intervalo de valores para a área hachurada, no eixo x, é P(125 < x < 150) = 45,22%.
Sei que essa área deve ser obtida com a função polygon(), mas não estou sabendo completar os argumentos.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: É uma área hachurada ou uma área pintada como na figura?

Comment: pode ser pintada mesmo. Como for mais fácil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie um segundo conjunto de dados para o polígono. Tirei os títulos, cores, etc, para destacar as partes relevantes do código:

```
# Plota a curva da FDP
x <- seq(100, 200, length = 1000)
y <- dnorm(x, mean = mean(dados), sd = sd(dados))
plot(x, y, type = "l")

# Cria e plota o polígono
x2 <- seq(125, 150, length = 100)
y2 <- dnorm(x2, mean = mean(dados), sd = sd(dados))
polygon(c(125, x2, 150), c(0, y2, 0), col = "gray")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Aqui vai uma solução com o pacote `ggplot2`.
Define-se uma função para criar uma base com valores para a densidade normal e para a área do intervalo pretendido. Esta área é dada por limites `lower` e `upper` que se `prob = TRUE` serão os valores de probabilidades.

### Função de cálculo.

Esta função utiliza o método da [resposta do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506903/82237). As alterações só a tornam mais geral, mas segue quase exatamente os mesmos passos.

```
data2normal <- function(x, lower, upper, n = 1000, prob = FALSE){
  Xlims <- range(pretty(x))
  X.bar <- mean(x)
  S <- sd(x)
  if(prob){
    lower <- qnorm(lower, X.bar, S)
    upper <- qnorm(upper, X.bar, S)
  }
  X <- seq(Xlims[1], Xlims[2], length = n)
  Y <- dnorm(X, mean = X.bar, sd = S)
  delta <- (upper - lower)/n
  x2 <- seq(lower + delta, upper - delta, length = n - 2)
  y2 <- dnorm(x2, mean = X.bar, sd = S)
  data.frame(x = X, y = Y, x2 = c(lower, x2, upper), y2 = c(0, y2, 0))
}
```

---

### Gráficos.

Agora os gráficos. É importante notar que o polígono é traçado antes da densidade. Se não for assim, a área sobrepõe-se à linha.

#### 1. O gráfico da pergunta.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data2normal(dados, 125, 150)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x2, y2), fill = "gray") +
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 2. Um intervalo de confiança 95%.

```
df2 <- data2normal(dados, 0.025, 0.975, prob = TRUE)

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x2, y2), fill = "pink") +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]